# Меняющаяся шапка в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Мне необходимо сделать на сайте WP сделать меняющуюся шапку наподобие gif-анимации.

Как лучше сделать:

- Обычную gif-ку поставить на шапку;
- Залить несколько картинок, и скриптами их менять;
- Есть какой-то стандартный плагин, и зря я пытаюсь придумать велосипед?

Comment: как хочешь так и делаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой [плагин "каруселей"](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/carousel)?

Answer (score 0):

Можно гифку использовать, а можно слайдер типа "карусель". Owl carousel, например.